# Slide page transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to apply a slide transition between divs with Jquery Mobile.
I have the below HTML structure:

```
// More content ... No jQuery Mobile needs
<div data-role="page">
   <a href="#p1" data-transition="slide">Go to #1.</a>
   <a href="#p2" data-transition="slide">Go to #2.</a>
</div>

<div id="p1" data-role="page">
   <div data-role="main">I am P 1</div>
</div>

<div id="p2" data-role="page">
   <div data-role="main">I am P 2</div>
</div>
```

I copied the structure from a [W3School demo](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_pages.asp). But doesn't work for me.
In first place, #p1 and #p2 hace display:block. And when i click the links the content doesn't change.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included `jQuery` and `jQueryMobile` correctly.Your code is working
as follows.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page">
       <a href="#p1" data-transition="slide">Go to #1.</a>
       <a href="#p2" data-transition="slide">Go to #2.</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="p1" data-role="page">
       <div data-role="main">I am P 1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="p2" data-role="page">
       <div data-role="main">I am P 2</div>
    </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```